# Table in Beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

I have one problems about the table in `beamer`. The table can be compiled in `\documentclass{article}`, but not in `\documentclass{beamer}`. Below is the table I make:

```
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
%\subfloat[Decay Channels]{
 %\rule{4cm}{3cm}
  \newcommand{\minitab}[2][l]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}
 %\renewcommand{\multirowsetup}{\centering}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
    Description & Basic cuts  \\ \hline
   \multirow{4}{*}{Jet} &${\bf p}_T >$ 25 GeV   \\
       &$|\eta| < $ 2.5   \\
       &$\Delta R(j,l) >$ 0.2  \\
       &$\Delta \phi(j,{\bf p}_T^{miss}) >$ 0.6  \\ \hline
    3 Leading jets & ${\bf p}_T >$ 40 GeV   \\ \hline
    b-tagging & $\ge$ 2 \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Lepton} & ${\bf p}_T >$ 20 GeV \\
           & $|\eta| <$ 2.5 \\
           & $\Delta R(l,j) >$ 0.4 \\ \hline
    {${\bf p}_T^{miss}$} & $\Delta \phi({\bf p}_T^{miss},j) >$ 0.8 \\ \hline
    & {\bf Advanced cuts} \\ \hline
    $E_T^{miss}$ & $>$ 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200 (GeV)\\ \hline
    $H_T$ & $>$ 400, 450, 500, 550, 600 (GeV)\\ \hline
    $m_T$ & $>$ 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200 (GeV)\\ \hline
    $N_j$ & $\ge$ 4, 5, 6 \\ \hline
    $N_{bj}$ & $\ge$ 2, 3, 4 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
%}
\caption{Summary of event selection cuts}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 8):

A `table` environment is floating around, which does not make sense within beamer, since it should appear on a particular, designed slide and is therefore suppressed (see comment by G. Medina) I removed the `table` stuff as well as the `\caption` and the wrong `\minitab` command.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{TestFrame}

    %\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    %\subfloat[Decay Channels]{
     %\rule{4cm}{3cm}
     % \newcommand{\minitab}[2][l]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}
     %\renewcommand{\multirowsetup}{\centering}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
        Description & Basic cuts  \\ \hline
       \multirow{4}{*}{Jet} &${\bf p}_T >$ 25 GeV   \\
           &$|\eta| < $ 2.5   \\
           &$\Delta R(j,l) >$ 0.2  \\
           &$\Delta \phi(j,{\bf p}_T^{miss}) >$ 0.6  \\ \hline
        3 Leading jets & ${\bf p}_T >$ 40 GeV   \\ \hline
        b-tagging & $\ge$ 2 \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{Lepton} & ${\bf p}_T >$ 20 GeV \\
               & $|\eta| <$ 2.5 \\
               & $\Delta R(l,j) >$ 0.4 \\ \hline
        {${\bf p}_T^{miss}$} & $\Delta \phi({\bf p}_T^{miss},j) >$ 0.8 \\ \hline
        & {\bf Advanced cuts} \\ \hline
        $E_T^{miss}$ & $>$ 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200 (GeV)\\ \hline
        $H_T$ & $>$ 400, 450, 500, 550, 600 (GeV)\\ \hline
        $m_T$ & $>$ 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200 (GeV)\\ \hline
        $N_j$ & $\ge$ 4, 5, 6 \\ \hline
        $N_{bj}$ & $\ge$ 2, 3, 4 \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
    %}
  %  \caption{Summary of event selection cuts}
  % \end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first part of your answer is not entirely right. `beamer` internally suppresses the flotation mechanism for `table` and `figure`, so it is perfectly safe to use them in `beamer` without the objects being floated away (see Section **12.6 Figures and Tables** of the `beamer` manual). The reason to have `figure` and `table` is to still be able to use of `\caption` for tables or figures (is such a caption is really required in a presentation).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Perhaps I did not have the problem with floating objects so far in `beamer`, because I barely use them at all, but it is good to know now